# Multiple ServiceInstaller in one ServiceProcessInstaller in Windows Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, service-installer

I have added two ServiceInstallers to my ServiceProcessInstaller. After that I haved changed my Main() as below:

```
static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        {
            new Service1(),
            new Service2()                
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

I have also set Service2 as dependent service on Service1 as below:

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Service1ProcessInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
        this.Service1Installer = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        this.Service2Installer = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
        // 
        // Service1ProcessInstaller
        // 
        this.Service1ProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        this.Service1ProcessInstaller.Password = null;
        this.Service1ProcessInstaller.Username = null;
        // 
        // Service1Installer
        // 
        this.Service1Installer.ServiceName = "Service1";
        this.Service1Installer.ServicesDependedOn = new string[] {"Service2"};
        // 
        // Service2Installer
        // 
        this.Service2Installer.ServiceName = "Service2";
        // 
        // ProjectInstaller
        // 
        this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
        this.Service1ProcessInstaller,
        this.Service1Installer,
        this.Service2Installer});

    }
```

still it is only running my Service1.

Service2 is never calling.

And if I change sequence in Main() then Service2 is only calling.

It is always calling first service.

How to call my both services?

Comment: If you open `services.msc` do you have two services there?

Comment: @zaitsman No I have not.It shows only myService.exe

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The problem was not with dependent service it was with my uninstallation.I have uninstalled my service and then installed it again and then I found both services in my Services.msc.

We need dependent service when they are actually dependent on each other so I have removed dependent service code too.

Now I can start them manually. and both of them are running. Below is my code which ran successfully.

```
static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
    {
        new Service1(),
        new Service2()                
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.Service1ProcessInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
    this.Service1Installer = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
    this.Service2Installer = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
    // 
    // Service1ProcessInstaller
    // 
    this.Service1ProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
    this.Service1ProcessInstaller.Password = null;
    this.Service1ProcessInstaller.Username = null;
    // 
    // Service1Installer
    // 
    this.Service1Installer.ServiceName = "Service1";
    // 
    // Service2Installer
    // 
    this.Service2Installer.ServiceName = "Service2";
    // 
    // ProjectInstaller
    // 
    this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
    this.Service1ProcessInstaller,
    this.Service1Installer,
    this.Service2Installer});

}
```

Comment: hi , thanks for your answer ,  how do you install to see 2 services?